# Consequences of using a Linked Server in a View

Tags: sql, view, linked-server

I know how to create and use a linked server with in a view, but my question is does having a linked server in a view hold the connection open and use the whole time or is the linked server only accessed and used when the view is used?

I am working on creating some dashboards and would like to use views in some places but wonder what if any consequences exist with using linked servers within a view.

-Thank you

(I am using MS SQL 2008 R2 to house the views, stored procedures, etc.)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A view can be thought of as either a virtual table or a stored query.
>   The data accessible through a view is not stored in the database as a
>   distinct object. What is stored in the database is a SELECT statement.
>   **The result set of the SELECT statement forms the virtual table
>   returned by the view.**

This is a quote from MSDN. Also you can find on MSDN linked server properties, which are e.g Connection and Query Timeouts.

Each time a view is meant to be shown, a proper sql is being sent to linked server, which replies with a resultset defined as a temp table unless a query timeout happens. Then connection is dropped.

Comment: I figured that is how it worked but I don't like to assume... Thanks for confirmingand I was able to find that on MSDN now becuase of your post. Thank you.